# wait(null) and wait(&status) C language and Status

Tags: c, unix, posix, wait, status

What is the difference between `wait(null)` and `wait(&status)` in c system programming?

And what is the content of the pointer status ?

Comment: Fixed your tags. THis is not really a C question, but a POSIX question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you call `wait(NULL)` ([wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)), you only wait for any child to terminate. With `wait(&status)` you wait for a child to terminate but you want to know some information about it's termination.

You can know if the child terminate normally with `WIFEXITED(status)` for example.

`status` contains information about processes that you can check with some already defined MACRO.

Answer (score 1):

`wait(NULL)` will only wait until the child process is completed.
But,
`wait(&status)` will return the process id of the child process that is terminated.

```
pid = wait(&status); // the information is returned
```